# Initializing a Mininet topology from a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, mininet

I'd like to automate the process of setting up a [Mininet](http://mininet.org) virtual machine, SSHing into the VM, starting Mininet within the VM, and initializing a topology. I need the session to remain open so I can issue commands to Mininet using the created network. Everything works, including initializing the network, but once the bash script ends, Mininet tears down the topology and exits the virtual machine. The relevant parts of my code are as follows:

```
vboxmanage startvm "Mininet-VM_1" --type=headless

ssh -t -Y -l mininet -p 2222 localhost << HERPDERP

    # Start the network
    sudo mn --controller=remote,ip=$ip --custom /home/mininet/sf_mininet_vm/mininet/topo_basic.py --topo clos_tree --switch ovsk --link tc

HERPDERP
```

Things I've tried:

1. Ending the *here* document with `s0 bash`;
2. Ending it with `s0 $SHELL`;
3. Removing the delimiter at the end of the *here* document (shot in the dark).

(1) and (2) exited Mininet and left me with a prompt in the VM, but for some reason I can't issue commands from it. (3) does nothing.

Comment: Isn't  a command for mininet `mn` ?

Comment: Yes, that is the command to initialize the network, but I was referring to commands within Mininet (e.g., pingall). I found that initializing the network is best handled through the Python API, e.g.:
    topo = SingleSwitchTopo(n=4)
    net = Mininet(topo)
    net.start()
    CLI(net)  # this line will start the Mininet CLI and leave it open to accept commands.

Comment: Ok, if you have that python topo in a file you can run the topo by just using `sudo -E python <nameofthefile>`

Comment: For example, if you have your topo in file [Pkt_Topo_with_loop.py](https://github.com/Ehsan70/RyuApps/blob/master/Pkt_Topo_with_loop.py), you could just use `sudo -E python Pkt_Topo_with_loop.py`. So you would have that line in your bash script.

Answer (score 0):

if you have that python topo in a file you can run the topo by just using

```
sudo -E python <nameofthefile>
```

For example, If you have your topo in file [Pkt_Topo_with_loop.py](https://github.com/Ehsan70/RyuApps/blob/master/Pkt_Topo_with_loop.py), you could just use `sudo -E python Pkt_Topo_with_loop.py` to start up the mininet. So you would have that line in your bash script for automation.